# Looking to split a string on the last space and a hyphen that comes after it

Tags: regex, r

I'm looking to separate a field into three fields: one with a city, and two for two different numbers.  The data looks something like this:

```
"Mt. Fuji 8-12"
"Taj Majal 10-03"    
"Ur"    
"Nairobi 04"
```

I want to split this field as follows (with `|` representing separations between fields):

```
"Mt. Fuji"  | 8    | 12
"Taj Majal" | 10   | 03
"Ur"        | ""   | ""
"Nairobi"   | "04" | ""
```

Since this is being done in R, I can also accept Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You may do like this,

```
> x <- "Mt. Fuji 8-12"
> strsplit(x, "[\\s-](?=\\d)", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "Mt. Fuji" "8"        "12"
```

`[\\s-]` matches a space character or hyphen only if it's `(?=\\d)` followed by a digit character. `(?=\\d)` positive lookahead assertion which asserts that the match ie, `[\s-]` must be followed by a digit character.

As @richard suggested..

```
stringi::stri_split_regex(x, "[\\s-](?=\\d)", simplify = TRUE)
```

Comment: could you explain your regexp please ... ?

Comment: The issue is when I do that, it keeps the hyphens and spaces in the resulting split string.  I'm looking to cut them when splitting.

Comment: Okay so it works on that one x, but if I do it on a column of a data frame, it keeps the split for some reason.  I'm using this command:

 sapply(as.character(test), strsplit, "[\\s-](?=\\d)", perl=TRUE)

Comment: Thanks Richard!  That's exactly what I needed.  Can you please put it in its own comment so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Okay then.  I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is for this.  Do I just Avinash's answer as correct?

Comment: what's wrong with `strsplit(as.character(test), "[\\s-](?=\\d)", perl=TRUE)` ?  works for me ...

Comment: (the `stringi` stuff with simplify is convenient because it adds `""` where necessary)

Comment: Ben, it was keeping the split characters in.  Like I'd have "Mt. Fuji " | "8" "-" "12"

Comment: @BrandonSherman that's not possible. How come you get the delimiters?

Comment: I have no idea, but Richard's solution didn't give me delimiters.